# Codeigniter 3.0.6 hmvc not working for individual module

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, hmvc

Hello friends its killing me please help me out from there. Actually i am trying to setup HMVC in codeigniter 3.0.6 and i have already setup as i watched tutorials but it is not working. Whenever i calling my controller showing 404 page not found.
I am describing here what i have done.

1. Downloaded the modular hmvc package from wiredesignz with Branch
   3.0.6
2. Extract the downloaded archive. Copy files from core directory to CodeIgniter’s application/core directory and copy files from third-party/MX to CodeIgniter’s application/third-party/MX.
3. Create a new folder called modules under application (application/modules)

   __application

   __modules

   __Home

   __controllers

   ```
    __Home.php
   ```

   __modules

   ```
    __home.php
   ```

   __views

   ```
    __home.php
   ```

Here Setup done.now when i running http://localhost/code_hmvc/index.php/Home/Home. Its says 404 Not Found.

Comment: Did you change in `autoload.php` and `config.php` files...?

Comment: Yes i have changes in config.php but not in autoload.php.

Comment: I tried and Its working fine at localhost. Kindly check [this](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src/f77a3fc9a6fdbfa47d70c921dac31d6d29a664e6?at=codeigniter-3.x) link.

Comment: what's "__" before files ?

Comment: Sorry Its nothing.It was only for folder structure hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar problems, and in the end I found out it was a naming PB & a .htaccess misconfiguration:

### Naming

Beware that lots of tutorial explains how it works with xamp  (apache server for windows) in a local environnment - mostly case insensitive.

eg : some tut will advice you to create a `home.php` file with a class `Home`. Fine, but didn't work for me at first : As I run under Linux I had to rename my file from `home.php` to `Home.php` in order to make it work.

In your exemple, your conrtoller file is name ***h***ome.php, meaning your class will work only if called ***h***ome and not ***H***ome if you run under linux (you should change the file naming as capital letter is conventionnal !)

- Make sure your main controller (calling the module) extends MX_Controllers.
- Also make sure your controller "home" extends MX
- Avoid capital letters in your URLs  `index.php/Home/Home` should be `index.php/home/` - if module has the same name than controller you can call it directly

### htaccess

And last but not least, it took me ages before finding the correct .htaccess to get rid off the "index.php" within HMVC and solve this dble repetition of controller/function (/home/home)

Can't find the original website where I took it, but this code worked for me

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # activate URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine on

    # do not rewrite links to the documentation, assets and public files
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt)

    # do not rewrite for php files in the document root, robots.txt or the maintenance page
    RewriteCond $1 !^([^\..]+\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)

    # but rewrite everything else
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 index.php

</IfModule>
```

**! WARNING !** : All being said, I have an issue with the conf described above : I can't get `modules::run()` working, where `modules::load()` works fine.. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868191/codeigniter-3-hmvc-modulesrun-wont-work-where-modulesload-does) for details