# Codeigniter 3 - HMVC ::run() & ::load() problems

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

I have issues when I try something as basic as, let's say,  displaying a login form to a user : I have a Users controller in my module Users that has a function login_form() supposed to display the form.  I also have a Controller Admin in my CI folder application/controllers/Admin.php which has a login() function that can call the user module.

*The problem :*

If I browse directly users/login_form, it works and calls the `login_form()` function.

But if Admin/login is browsed and calls Users/login_form as a module, I can't access use `modules::run()` - I have to use `modules::load()`

**I tried with only a simple execution where class constructors and methods just write their name & loaded path (*see full code below*)**

**TEST A params**

```
// URI called : admin/login
// Admin extends MX | Users extends MX 

// called from Admin::login()
$this->users = Modules::load('users')->login_form();
```

**result**

```
// class constructor - extends
Admin - MX_Controller
# Fx in Admin
Fx : login 

// class constructor - extends
Users - MX_Controller
# Fx in users
Fx : login_form
```

So while `Modules::load()` allows me to access the users/login_form method from Admin, I can't get `Modules::run()` working ...

**TEST B (not working) params**

```
// URI called : admin/login
// Admin extends MX | Users extends MX 

// called from Admin::login()
$this->users = Modules::run('users/login_form');
```

**result**

```
// same result as above for Admin

// class constructor - extends 
Users - MX_Controller 
# !! login_form() FROM USERS IS NOT EXECUTED !!
```

**TEST A does execute the `login_form()` function, but although TEST B do load the constructor of the Users Class, it never reaches the `login_form()` function ...**

I was wondering if it could be a routing problem, but as the constructor of the class Users is called in both run & load, I doubt this could be that ..

## Full Code

Admin controller (application/controllers/Admin.php) :

```
class Admin extends MX_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo get_class().' - '.get_parent_class()." [".dirname(__FILE__)."]<br>\n";

    }

    function login()
    {
        echo  "Fx : ".__FUNCTION__."<br>\n";

        // works fine 
        // loads the Users class constructor
        // execute login_form()
        Modules::load('users')->login_form();

        // Does only load User constructor
        // Modules::run('users/login_form');
    }
}
```

Users Controller (application/modules/users/controllers/Users.php)

```
class Users extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        echo get_class().' - '.get_parent_class()." [".dirname(__FILE__)."]<br>\n";

    }

    public function login_form()
    {
        echo  "Fx : ".__FUNCTION__."<br>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `class User extends CI_Controller {` should be `class User extends MX_Controller {`.

Comment: And when use `Modules::run('module/controller/function');`

Comment: Tpojka is right : class Users has to extends MX, otherwise Users doesn't have the CI->load ->config etc (though it does not solve my problem of paths!) . I've tried wolfgang solution (`Modules::run('users/users/login_form')`) but it didn't change a thing .. Updated my question to be more relevant